# How to solve this problem on alligations?

Tags: natural-numbers, ratio

Question:

"The diluted wine contains only 8 litres of wine and the rest is water. A new mixture whose initial concentration is 30 %, is to be formed by replacing wine. How many litres of mixture shall be replaced with pure wine if there was initially 32 litres of water in the mixture?"

Doubt:

I intend to solve this by the alligation formula but I am not being able to do the same. Please guide.

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: I agree.  It is not clear what the difference is between "mixture," "new mixture," "initial new mixture," and "diluted wine."  Also the action of "replacing wine" in this context is unclear.